# Correct way to match path inside a URL? (8)

Tags: javascript

Derived from JavaScript, The Good Parts, is a regex for matching URLs.

**pseudo code (each number represents a sub-expression)**

```
/^(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)$/
```

In the 5 spot is this regex with some other things.

```
[^?#]*
```

Pretty simple, It is just a not character class, to match everything except `?` or `#`, as these will later be used to match a query and a fragment identifier.

However, I want to replace this with a character class that does not use not - `^`

The first thing I was not sure of was whether or not Unicode can be used in a path.  If it can't I was planning on using an ASCII character set.

**Clarification:**  I don't want to use negative look ahead as this emulates a not character set.

**Reference:**  Here is the complete regex broken up into different lines for each part.

```
/^
(?:([a-zA-Z]+):)?
(\/{0,3})
([a-zA-Z0-9.\-]+)
(?::(\d+))?
(?:\/([^#?]*))?
(?:\?([^#]))?
(?:#(.*))?
$/
```

Comment: Not use `not ^` ... so you mean essentially `[^^]*`? You should try it then

Comment: See the [purl](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl/blob/master/purl.js) regexps

Comment: Why would you want to do this while being generic enough to permit Unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code points allowed are ASCII alpha numeric and described in this [url spec](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urls).

> The URL code points are ASCII alphanumeric, "!", "$", "&", "'", "(",
>   ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "=", "?", "@", "_", "~",
>   and code points in the ranges U+00A0 to U+D7FF, U+E000 to U+FDCF,
>   U+FDF0 to U+FFEF, U+10000 to U+1FFFD, U+20000 to U+2FFFD, U+30000 to
>   U+3FFFD, U+40000 to U+4FFFD, U+50000 to U+5FFFD, U+60000 to U+6FFFD,
>   U+70000 to U+7FFFD, U+80000 to U+8FFFD, U+90000 to U+9FFFD, U+A0000 to
>   U+AFFFD, U+B0000 to U+BFFFD, U+C0000 to U+CFFFD, U+D0000 to U+DFFFD,
>   U+E1000 to U+EFFFD, U+F0000 to U+FFFFD, U+100000 to U+10FFFD.

Further reference by W3 is available [here:](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt)

Comment: I copied it directly, but yes.

Answer (score 4):

You could also facilitate browser parsing logic:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```